# Target Windows 10 SDK using MSBuild Tools v120

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

I have Win32 C++ project that generates a DLL. I use Visual Studio 2022 as my IDE.
For compatibility reasons, I must build it using MSBuild Tools v120. I cannot use newer versions of MSBuild.
My problem arised when trying to use header files only available in the Windows 10 SDK (10.0.22621.0). As I understand from these configurations, Visual Studio is using the Windows 8.1 SDK.
[image: VC++ Directories]
[image: VC++ Include Directories Configuration]

In my project's configuration, when I switch to MSBuild Tools v143, Visual Studio lets me select which Windows SDK I want to use. When I do, the VC++ Directories configuration changes and targets the right SDK.
[image: Windows SDK Selection when using v143]
[image: VC++ Directories with Build Tools v143 + Windows 10 SDK]

However, there's no such option when I use MSBuild Tools v120
[image: No Windows SDK option when using v120]

I tried to retarget the solution like this
[image: Retarget Solution Window]
This is the output from that process
[image: retarget output]

But I have the same issue: Visual Studio does not find the headers I need. When I look at the Visual Studio WindowsSDK-related macros, they're still pointing to the Windows 8.1 SDK.

How is Visual Studio choosing to use the Windows 8.1 SDK? How should I target the Windows 10 SDK using MSBuild Tools v120 in Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: Using *VS2013* as an *IDE*, might simplify your problem. "*My problem arised when trying to use header files only available in the Windows 10 SDK*". Don't use them, use something that's proven / known to work / officially supported by your Platform tools.

Comment: @CristiFati This suggests an incompatibility for which I cannot find evidence. The Windows SDK doesn't need much build system support, and seeing that Windows 10 was released in 2015, it would come as a surprise that VS 2013 wasn't supported.

Comment: @IInspectable: I can't find an official source either stating there's an incompatibility. All I know is that before *VStudio2015*, *VStudio* versions and *VStudio SDK* versions were bound. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2013/vs2013-compatibility-vs.

Comment: @CristiFati Right, that makes sense. I keep forgetting that VS 2015 was the Big Move, liberating the IDE/compiler from platform entanglement. For VS 2013/v120 toolset, this means: Keep using the Windows 8.1 SDK. If you need access to system services introduced in Windows 10 or later, you're on your own (manually declaring interfaces, linking against newer import .libs/delegating to run-time dynamic linking, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some aspects unclear to me, like:

- *MSBuild Tools 120* compatibility restriction
- The need to use *Win 10 SDK*

So far, I found **no official resource** stating that the 2 are incompatible (but we all know that sometimes *MS* documentation is not as clear as it should be). I found some articles:

- [[MSDN.Social]: Windows-SDK vs. Visual-Studio compatibility?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ba92a782-c5a4-4aa1-8b1f-4a329fbabd21/windowssdk-vs-visualstudio-compatibility?forum=vcgeneral)
- [[SO]: Windows-SDK vs. Visual-Studio compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47156471/4788546)

*VStudio 14* (*2105*) was the 1<sup>st</sup> version that ensured (among other things) *VStudio* version and *Win SDK* version interoperability. Prior to that, a *Win SDK* version was bound to a *VStudio* version (and it was called *Platform SDK*). Their (unofficial) versions history:

- [[Wikipedia]: Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio)
- [[Wikipedia]: Microsoft Windows SDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK)

[[MS.Learn]: Visual Studio 2013 Platform Targeting and Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2013/vs2013-compatibility-vs) **lists *Win 8.1* as the latest** targeted desktop platform.
As a consequence, if *Win 10* is not supported, there's no reason to use *Win 10* specific things (*Win 10 SDK*).
So, not being able to combine the 2 (from *VStudio 2022*) could be *MS*'s way of telling you that you shouldn't.
On the other hand, I was able to run an app built with *VStudio 2013* on *Win 10* (not a *Hello World*, but a complex one that had a bunch of *.dll*s and also drivers).

**Ways to go further**:

1. Switch (the whole project) to a newer *VStudio* version. After all, this is the recommended and normal way. I understand that in some cases (especially involving large projects) it's a major burden, but at some point this will have to be done anyway. Also (according to [[MS.DevBlogs]: Support reminder for older versions of Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/support-reminder-for-older-versions-of-visual-studio)) *VStudio 2013* will run out of (extended) support in ~6 months (*2024/04/09*). Of course it will still work, but generally, customers are a bit paranoid about code (and adjacent tools) running in their environments
2. Use *VStudio 2013 IDE* (latest update). Your setup is complex (*VStudio 2022*, *VStudio 2013 Tools*, *Win 10 SDK*) and not helping. Maybe if using a simpler one, things won't be that complicated
3. Don't rely *Win 10 SDK*, but whatever you're using from there (I must point again to the 1<sup>st</sup> paragraph in the answer) could be replaced with stuff from *Win 8.1 SDK* (or older)
4. Set the (include and libraries) paths manually (for advanced developers only). Even if the build would succeed, note that there may be unexpected results at runtime. **Use with care** (as it's most likely an *Unsupported Configuration*)

Unfortunately, now I'm (dual) booted on *Nix* and I can't do any tests of my own (I do have installed more than 10 working *VStudio* versions).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The link [\[MSDN.Social\]: Windows-SDK vs. Visual-Studio compatibility?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ba92a782-c5a4-4aa1-8b1f-4a329fbabd21/windowssdk-vs-visualstudio-compatibility?forum=vcgeneral) answers the question about how to target Windows 10 SDK on VS2013. 
Seeing that VS2013 and Win10SDK is not explicitly supported, I'll take the time to solve my dependencies and migrate to VS2022 build tools.